# Continuity of solutions of ODEs with Dirac delta forcing

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

The problem is : Find $y$, if $y''-4y=\delta(x-a)$, where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function, and $y$ is bounded as $|x|\rightarrow\infty$.

The solution goes like this:

For $x<a$, $y=Ae^{2x}+Be^{-2x}$, and because of the boundary condition, $B=0$, so $y=Ae^{2x}$.

For $x>a$, $y=Ce^{2x}+De^{-2x}$, and because of the boundary condition, $C=0$, so $y=De^{-2x}$.

At $x=a$, the solution must be continuous, so $Ae^{2a}=De^{-2a}$.

Also, the integral from $a^-$ to $a^+$ of the LHS of the equation must be equal to the same integral of the RHS of the equation, which is 1. This gives the other needed equation for $A$ and $D$ from which we can easily find the general solution (I didn't write it as it is irrelevant for the question, but if anyone cares, the general solution is $y=-\dfrac{e^{-2|x-a|}}4$ for $y\neq a$).

My question is: why must $y$ be continuous at $a$? 
An explanation that I have seen is the following:

If $y$ had a simple discontinuity (finite jump) at $a$, then $y'$ would have a $\delta$-function singularity at $a$, and so would $y''$, but there is nothing in the equation to balance such a singularity.

I think that this is an incorrect explanation, as $y''$ would actually have a -2-singularity at $x=a$, while $\delta$-singularity is -1-singularity. This offers an explanation, as the equation doesn't balance out -2-singularities, but is there a more rigorous and simpler proof why $y$ is continuous at $a$?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the quoted explanation is incorrect: the singularity of $y''$ would be of higher order (a distribution of order $1$, to be precise), and there is no such thing in the equation.

The question of "why must the solution be continuous" is always tied to "what do we mean by *solution*"? For that matter, what does the equation $y''−4y=\delta (x−a)$ mean? What is $y''$ here? The equation cannot be understood in terms of classical derivatives (limit of difference quotient). If $y''$ is the classical 2nd order derivative of $y$, then it is a function, and being added to $-4y$, it is still a function and not a point mass.

One of possible answers is: $y$ is a distribution such that $y''$ is a Radon measure, and the sum of two measures $y''$ and $-4y(t)\,dt$ is the point mass at $a$. But if $y''$ is a Radon measure, then $y'$ is a function of bounded variation on every bounded interval. It follows that $y$ is a Lipschitz function on every bounded interval, and in particular it is continuous.

---

Update. One possible answer is: $y$ must be continuous because we say so. It's up to us to decide what we accept as a solution to any problem. For this problem, we decide that $y$ is a solution if it is continuous everywhere, has derivatives $y',y''$ when $x\ne a$, and these derivatives satisfy equation. If such continuous $y$ did not exist, we would then say that the equation has no solution.

I do not have a satisfactory explanation in terms that you were given. The following is just an attempt to connect the story somehow. Consider the approximate equation where $\delta(x-a)$ is replaced with $D(x-a,h)$. Following the method of doraemonpaul, we find 
$$y=C_1e^{2x}+C_2e^{-2x}+\dfrac{1}{4} \int_a^x \left(e^{2(x-t)}-e^{2(t-x)}\right) D(t-a,h)\,dt$$
As $h\to 0$, $D$ grows large in the sense of pointwise values, but its integral stays equal to $1$. This suggests integration by parts: we throw the integral onto $D(t-a,h)$, turning it into something similar to the Heaviside function, let's say $H(t-a,h)$. 
$$y=C_1e^{2x}+C_2e^{-2x}+\dfrac{1}{2} \int_a^x \left(e^{2(x-t)}+e^{2(t-x)}\right) H(t-a,h)\,dt$$
This is less convenient for practical computation than the original integral, but the advantage is that we have a more reasonable function $H(t-a,h)$ which converges  to a reasonable function $H(t-a)$. In particular, $H$ stays bounded as $h\to 0$, which means that the differences such as $|y(x)-y(x')| $ can be effectively estimated from above:
$$\left|\int_x^{x'} \left(e^{2(x-t)}+e^{2(t-x)}\right) H(t-a,h)\,dt\right|\le M|x-x'|\tag{L}$$ 
where $M$ is the supremum of whatever is under the integral sign. This (L) is the Lipschitz property that I was talking about in the comments, but you can read it simply as continuity.

Comment: Thanks, but could you please explain the last bit again, I'm a first year undergrad student and we haven't mentioned neither Radon measures nor Lipschitz functions in our classes?

Comment: @user61436 I'll be happy to, but you should tell me how $\delta(x-a)$ was defined in your course.

Comment: First they considered a family of function $D(t,h)$ such that $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} D(t,h)=0$ for all $t\neq 0$ and $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \int_{-\infty}^\infty D(t,h)dt = 1$. Then $\delta(x)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} D(x,h)$. They told us that $\delta$ wasn't a function and that its integral properties could only be used, etc.

Comment: @user61436 After some delay, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just solve it by variation of parameters as usual.

$y_1=e^{2x}$ , $y_2=e^{-2x}$

The Wronskian of these two functions is $\begin{vmatrix}e^{2x}&e^{-2x}\\2e^{-2x}&-2e^{-2x}\\\end{vmatrix}=-4$

$\therefore y=C_1e^{2x}+C_2e^{-2x}-e^{2x}\int_a^x\dfrac{1}{-4}e^{-2x}\delta(x-a)~dx+e^{-2x}\int_a^x\dfrac{1}{-4}e^{2x}\delta(x-a)~dx=C_1e^{2x}+C_2e^{-2x}+\dfrac{e^{2(x-a)}H(x-a)}{4}-\dfrac{e^{2(a-x)}H(x-a)}{4}=C_1e^{2x}+C_2e^{-2x}+\dfrac{(e^{2(x-a)}-e^{2(a-x)})H(x-a)}{4}$

Comment: That's correct, but it doesn't answer the question.