# Finding jump conditions

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

I have the equation:

$ \dfrac{1}{r^2}\dfrac{d}{dr}\left( r^2 \dfrac{d y(r,t)}{dr} \right) - \dfrac{ y(r,t)}{r^2} = S \delta(r-a(t)) $

where S is a function of t alone, and I want to find jump conditions across the point r=a. My attempt is:

$ \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\int _{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon}dr\dfrac{d}{dr}\left( r^2 \dfrac{d y(r,t)}{dr} \right) - \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\int _{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon}dr \;y(r,t) = $

$ \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \left[ r^2 \dfrac{d y(r,t)}{dr} \right]_{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon}  = S \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\int _{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon}dr\; r^2\delta(r-a(t)) = S \;a^2$

$ \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \left[  \dfrac{d y(r,t)}{dr} \right]_{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon}   = S \;$

Is there a way from the initial equation itself that I can be sure that y(r,t) is continuous and therefore get rid of the second integral on the LHS between steps 1 and 2?

Answer (score 1):

At some level of informality, one can argue [like here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/297701): if $y$ had a jump discontinuity, then $y'$ would have a Dirac delta component (distribution of order $0$), and $y''$ would contain the derivative of $\delta$ (distribution of order $1$). But there is nothing in the equation that can cancel out such a singular distribution.

Also informally, one could say: I want mass $S$ at $r=a$, this is going to come from the highest derivative (by the reasoning as above: if the singularity we want came from a lower order derivative, then the highest order derivative would have a singularity of the kind we do not want). Therefore, $(r^2y')$  should have a jump of size $Sa^2$ at $r=a$. This means $y'$ should have a jump of size $S$ at $r=a$. Then you write down a solution according to this and say: I have a solution, it's evidently continuous, and the existence theorem says it's the only one (for given initial conditions).

If you want to have a formal proof of continuity of solution, you need a precise definition of  *solution*. Such a definition will impose some requirements on $y$, and continuity will be one of them.